# Confirmed SQL Injection in VB.NET code using OleDb and Oracle, even though using parametrized query! How come is it possible?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oledb, sql-injection, code-injection

I'm probing this system for SQL Injection and found out even using Parametrized Query, exactly as suggested by [SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), it is still possible to execute SQL Injection!

**VB.NET Code and Query:**

```
Dim OleCommand As New OleDbCommand("SELECT name, age FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%' || ? || '%'", OleConnection)
OleCommand.Parameters.Add("name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_name.Text
```

**Example of Injections used successfully:**

```
' UNION ALL select banner,null from v$version --
' UNION ALL select username,null from ALL_USERS --
```

During all my researches (including some topics in Satckoverflow) I always read on how Parametrized Queries are enough to prevent SQL Injection, so I'm surprised it is not!

Can anyone please give me a detailed explanation on how and why is it possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is name? Seems to be a field name but you use as a parameter. This seems to be a coding error.

Comment: I don't think you are actually using parameters, you are still concatenating the SQL string with the `||` operator. Try rewriting your query as `"SELECT name, age FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%?%'"`

Comment: @Steve, actually this is just a representation of the real system, the names used are obfuscated because I can't disclosure any information of the original system. "name" in this case is the name of a column in the table people, but actually the real name of the columns doesn't really use "restricted" or "reserved" words.

Comment: Wolf, that't exactly my only clue! I will ask developers to remove the concatenation and test again. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What happen if you write `OleCommand.Parameters.Add("name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" + txt_name.Text +"%"` and remove the string concatenation in the query text?

Comment: Sorry for last comment. I am not sure about previous information I provided. I believe developers didn't do the deploy correctly. I will need to wait until tomorrow, then I will be able to check personaly with the them. Thank you guys for suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, It's embarrassing...

Actually the development team didn't deploy the fixed code correctly, so I was testing the old code, therefore, the vulnerability seemed to persist.

in short: above code is actually protected from SQL Injection!

Sorry for delay and thank you Wolf and Steve for your ideas.